# Flutter getting a specific field from firebase and assigning it to list

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am trying to query data from firestore and assign it to a List.
My users collection is as follows[image]

```
List<String> emailList = ['Select email', 'email1', 'email2'];
```

I am trying to populate the above emaillist with  the emails of persons such that the list is populated by emails of the persons where the groupId is equal to groupId of current user.
I tried querying by Firebase.instance.collection.where but it gets an error saying it cant be assigned to a List.
Any idea on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the issue is how you are adding to the list. You have to loop through the snapshot query and for each document, add to the list.

```
Firestore.instance.collection('users').getDocuments().then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.documents.forEach((doc) {
        emailList.add(doc.data['email']);
    })
});
```

Hope this helps!